# Hive use variable from a query that return only one value

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql

I would like to use something like:

```
set hivevar:average = select avg(nvl(val,0)) as average from table;
```

and Then use on another table like:

```
select * from table2 where value>=${average}
```

**Is this possible in hive? if not how is the correct way on doing**

Comment: Hive variables work as substitution, they are not calculated. Read this answer please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37821218/2700344

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HiveQL: Using query results as variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206449/hiveql-using-query-results-as-variables)

Comment: @leftjoin - while your solution is O.K., your reasoning ("Hive does not support such variables") is very unclear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42785704/hive-how-to-pass-hivevar-in-query/42785933#42785933

Comment: @Dudu Markovitz Updated the answer.